# Improving the performance of a MySQL left join sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have the following MySQL query which calculates the total number of orders for each month within a given date range e.g. a year. The query works correctly, but the performance is slow (around 250ms).

Any ideas on how to rewrite it to make it more efficient?

```sql
WITH recursive `dates` AS (
    (
        SELECT '2019-11-28' AS item
    )
    UNION
    ALL (
        SELECT
            item + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        FROM
            `dates`
        WHERE
            item + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2020-11-27'
    )
)
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`item`, '%b %y') AS `date`,
    COUNT(`orders`.`id`) AS `total`
FROM
    `dates`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            `orders`.`id`,
            `orders`.`created_at`
        FROM
            `orders`
            INNER JOIN `locations` ON `orders`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
        WHERE
            `orders`.`shop_id` = 10379184
            AND `locations`.`country_id` = 128
            AND `orders`.`created_at` >= '2019-11-28 12:01:42'
            AND `orders`.`created_at` <= '2020-11-27 12:01:42'
    ) AS `orders` ON DATE(`orders`.`created_at`) = `dates`.`item`
GROUP BY
    `date`
```

**UPDATE**: Some have suggested using two left joins, however if I do that then the `country_id` filter is not applied:

```sql
WITH recursive `dates` AS (
    (
        SELECT
            '2019-11-28' AS item
    )
    UNION
    ALL (
        SELECT
            item + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        FROM
            `dates`
        WHERE
            item + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2020-11-27'
    )
)
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`item`, '%b %y') AS `date`,
    COUNT(`orders`.`id`) AS `total`
FROM
    `dates`
    LEFT JOIN `orders` USE INDEX (`orders_created_at_index`) ON DATE(`created_at`) = `dates`.`item`
    AND `orders`.`shop_id` = 10379184
    AND `orders`.`created_at` >= '2019-11-28 12:22:43'
    AND `orders`.`created_at` <= '2020-11-27 12:22:43'
    LEFT JOIN `locations` ON `orders`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
    AND `locations`.`country_id` = 128
GROUP BY
    `date`
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the purpose of the (LEFT JOIN) subquery? Can't you simply LEFT JOIN just orders table instead?

Comment: Qualify your column names so it is clear where the columns are coming frm.

Comment: Why not simply `... FROM dates LEFT JOIN orders LEFT JOIN locations ...`? What's the reason to use a subquery?

Comment: The reason for the sub query is that if I use two left joins, then country_id does not get applied e.g.

```sql
LEFT JOIN `orders` USE INDEX (`orders_created_at_index`) ON DATE(`created_at`) = `dates`.`item`
AND `orders`.`shop_id` = 10379184
AND `orders`.`created_at` >= '2019-11-28 12:22:43'
AND `orders`.`created_at` <= '2020-11-27 12:22:43'
LEFT JOIN `locations` ON `orders`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
AND `locations`.`country_id` = 128
```

Comment: Left joins are needed to preserve the `WITH RECURSIVE` dates that are generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tinkering, I produced the following which operates in under 40ms, which is good enough for my needs. I still think it's not ideal and would welcome any improvements...

```sql
SELECT
    `date`,
    COUNT(`order`)
FROM
    (
        WITH recursive `dates` AS (
            (
                SELECT
                    '2019-11-28' AS item
            )
            UNION
            ALL (
                SELECT
                    item + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                FROM
                    `dates`
                WHERE
                    item + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2020-11-27'
            )
        )
        SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(`item`, '%b %y') AS `DATE`,
            `orders`.`id` AS `order`,
            `locations`.`id` AS `location`
        FROM
            `dates`
        LEFT JOIN 
            `orders` 
        ON 
            DATE(`created_at`) = `dates`.`item`
        AND 
            `orders`.`shop_id` = 10379184
        AND 
            `orders`.`created_at` >= '2019-11-28 12:22:43'
        AND 
            `orders`.`created_at` <= '2020-11-27 12:22:43'
        LEFT JOIN 
            `locations` 
        ON 
            `orders`.`location_id` = `locations`.`id`
        AND 
            `locations`.`country_id` = 209
    ) AS items
WHERE
    (
        `order` IS NULL
        AND `location` IS NULL
    )
    OR (
        `order` IS NOT NULL
        AND `location` IS NOT NULL
    )
GROUP BY
    `date`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(d.item, '%b %y') AS `date`,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM orders o JOIN
             locations l
             ON o.location_id = l.id
        WHERE shop_id = 10379184 AND
              country_id = 128 AND
              o.created_at >= d.item AND
              o.created_at < d.item + interval 1 day
       ) as total
FROM dates d;
```

This avoids the outer aggregation, which is often a performance improvement.

In addition, indexes could probably help the query, but it is unclear where columns such as `country_id` and `shop_id` are coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the count doesn't give the right value. `country_id` is on the `locations` table. `shop_id` is on the `orders` table.

Comment: How would you group by `date` and sum the `total`?

Comment: @MattKingshott . . . This counts the total on the date.  There is no need for aggregation.